# Android in-app billing Error: This item could no be purchased. (Error code: IAB-DPTL)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, error-code

I'm just beginning to use the android in-app billing system.
I tested the Dungeons application sample without any problems.

So I'm trying to integrate in-app in my own application, but when I use declared productId or static test id, I'm getting the same error:

```
This item could not be purchased. (Error code: IAB-DPTL)
```

This application is already on the market. I uploaded a signed version that I also pushed
on the phone (so it's the same version on both sides). I added the email wich is used on the phone as a test account. Should I activate my application ? (incurring the risk to remove the current published application ?)

I don't see what I'm missing, and I'm not able to find anything about this error code on the web.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No idea, but I am getting this too. You might want to try with a different test account, not sure if it will help.

Comment: Changing devices and/or accounts doesn't seem to help. Still getting the same error. Might be a Google glitch.

Comment: Ok thanks for you comments ! I'm not alone ! I'll try to investigate from the application received callbacks. I'll let you know.

Comment: Just a note: I've been using IAB for year, and this used to work (with occasional hiccups).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok I found the solution !!!

The bug is directly caused by the "payloadContent" which I associate to the productId during
the purchase request.

I used to convert my purchasable item into JSON and to put it as the developer payload content. (thought useful for the restoration phase...)

I tested to remove this payloadContent and then I had no more problems.

I think the data format used during the different transactions is JSON and so JSON payload content field should interfere with some waited fields.. (such "title" or "link")

UPDATE:

As Nikolay Elenkov said, the error is most probably caused by the length of the payload, and JSON seems to work. So there is a limitation in the developper payload size: 256 characters.

And we think that the error code:"IAB-DPTL" directly meens: "In App Billing - Developer Payload Too Long"

Thanks Nikolay !

Comment: I can confirm that removing developer payload solves this. I'll have to test, but are you sure you are not hitting the 256 character limit? Also accept your answer, so that the question is marked as answered.

Comment: Sending JSON definitely works, the error is most probably caused by the length of the payload. In my tests 270 chars cause it, 230 works.

Comment: You can also try complaining about the cryptic error message here: http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/list Now that we know the cause it seems obvious enough though: Developer Payload Too Long (DPTL).