# (Possibly) undocumented error when purchasing an item with Android In-App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm having issues performing purchases with Android's IAB.

I seem to be able to get the buyIntent, and I start it with this code, taken from the IAB [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html):

```
Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(),
                    sku, "inapp", getString(R.string.iab_key));

int response = buyIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if(response == 0) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                        1001, new Intent(), 0, 0, 0);
}
```

However, when the intent starts, I get an error message on the app stating "Item purchase impossible (Error code IAB-LPD)" (loosely translated from Italian), and in the `onActivityResult` method, when doing

```
int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
```

I get a `responseCode` of 2, that is not documented in the [IAB API reference](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html), as it documents error codes 0, 1, 3, 4 and so on.

The Api V2 Reference says that error code 2 is for the case when the network connection is down, but my device's connection seems to be working ok.

I also haven't found any reference to the error code "IAB-LPD" anywhere on the Internet.

I tried changing my License key to an invalid value, and I expectedly got an error message stating "This app is not authorized for billing", so I assume it's not a problem with the license key I'm using.

What am I missing?

**Update**: I also don't think it's an issue with permissions, as I'm able to get SKU details from the same technique described in the documentation.

**Further update**: I also don't get any errors in LogCat, neither when starting the intent nor when executing `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the error message you see is

```
Impossibile acquistare l'articolo. (Codice di errore: IAB-LPD)
```

There seems to be an error in the Italian translation of that message (the error code has been translated).

The error message you are looking for is

```
The item could not be purchased. (Error code: IAB-DPTL)
```

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194120/android-in-app-billing-error-this-item-could-no-be-purchased-error-code-iab) should help you address your problem.

(I apologize for the inconvenience, I submitted a fix for the error and it should be fixed in the upcoming releases.)